# Sharded mongodb cluster use only one shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I'm trying to create a sharded mongodb cluster, I have 3 VM to use and I was trying to get the following setup:

> VM1) Node.js Application + mongos instance
>
> VM2) CSRS PRIMARY + Shard
>
> VM3) CSRS SECONDARY + Shard

I'm not interested in replication but I need sharding because I will have to query over large number of results.
To achieve what stated above I have done the following:

### On both VM2 and VM3

```
mongod –configsvr  --replSet configM4C –bind_ip <ipVM2/3> --port 27040
mongod –shardsvr --replSet shardM4C --bind_ip <ipVM2/3> --port 27041
```

### Then, connected to the configM4C on VM2(*mongo --host  --port 27040*) and run

```
rs.initiate({
    _id:”configM4C”,
    configsvr: true,
    members: [
        {_id: 0, host: “<ipVM2>:27040”},
        {_id:1, host: “<ipVM3>:27040”}
    ]
})
```

### Then, connected to shardM4C on VM2(*mongo --host  --port 27041*) and run

```
rs.initiate({
    _id: shardM4C,
    members: [
        {_id: 0, host: “<ip1>:27041”},
        {_id:1, host: “<ip2>:27041”}
    ]
})
```

### Started mongos on VM1

```
mongos –configdb configM4C/<ipVM2>:27040,<ipVM3>:27040 --port 27042
```

### Connected to mongos on VM1(*mongo --port 27042*):

```
sh.addShard("<ipVM2>:27041)
sh.addShard("<ipVM3>:27041)
sh.enableSharding("pings")
sh.shardCollection("pings.pings", {provider:1, from_zone: 1, to_zone: 1})
```

### Anyway at this point if I run *db.pings.getShardDistribution()* I get:

```
Shard shardM4C at shardM4C/<ipVM3>:27041,<ipVM2>:27041
data : 19.47MiB docs : 102876 chunks : 1
estimated data per chunk : 19.47MiB
estimated docs per chunk : 102876

Totals
data : 19.47MiB docs : 102876 chunks : 1
Shard shardM4C contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 198B
```

### sh.status():

```
 sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("5b58a6b4986cc2d94694a3f9")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "shardM4C",  "host" : "shardM4C/10.0.0.4:27041,10.0.0.7:27041",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "3.6.3" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  5
        Last reported error:  Could not find host matching read preference { mode: "primary" } for set shardM4C
        Time of Reported error:  Wed Jul 25 2018 21:44:24 GMT+0000 (UTC)
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours: 
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
                config.system.sessions
                        shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shardM4C    1
                        { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shardM4C Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "pings",  "primary" : "shardM4C",  "partitioned" : true }
                pings.pings
                        shard key: { "provider" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                shardM4C    1
                        { "provider" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "provider" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : shardM4C Timestamp(1, 0) 
        {  "_id" : "test",  "primary" : "shardM4C",  "partitioned" : false }
```

### And if I run a query in the executionStats I get:

```
...
"queryPlanner" : {
        "mongosPlannerVersion" : 1,
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
            "shards" : [
                {
                    "shardName" : "shardM4C",
                    "connectionString" : "shardM4C/<ipVM3>:27041,<ipVM2>:27041",
                    "serverInfo" : {
                        "host" : "dpiscaglia-2",
                        "port" : 27041,
                        "version" : "3.6.3",
                        "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
                    },
...
```

Both results makes me think that the query is actually working on only one shard, and the second is used only for replication and as a backup(which is not what i want), am i correct?

If yes could you please help me understand what I did wrong?

Thank you very much in advance for your help
Have a good day